# d3 zoom: pan axis on scroll, pan axis on drag, zoom axis on pinch

Tags: d3.js

I'm hoping to configure the zoom behavior of a plot to have three kinds of interaction:

- It should be possible to pan from left to right with the scroll wheel.
- It should be possible to pan from left to right with mousedown drag events.
- it should be possible to zoom in 1-D with the pinch event (i.e. scroll wheel with control key pressed).

Right now, I can get the latter two to work in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s1t7mrpw/6/

The zoomed function looks like this:

```
function zoomed() {

  if (d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey || d3.event.sourceEvent.type === 'mousemove') {

    view.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    centerline.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x)));
    d3.event.transform.y = 0;
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);

  } else {

    current_transform = d3.zoomTransform(view);
    current_transform.x = current_transform.x - d3.event.sourceEvent.deltaY;

    // what do I do here to pan the axis and update `view`'s transform? 
    // centerline.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x))); ? 
    // view.attr('transform', current_transform); ? 

    g.attr('transform', current_transform);
  }
}
```

It uses the rescale nomenclature from these blocks:

- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/db6b4335bf1662b413e7968910104f0f
- https://bl.ocks.org/rutgerhofste/5bd5b06f7817f0ff3ba1daa64dee629d

And it uses [d3-xyzoom](https://github.com/wiremind/d3-xyzoom) for independent scaling in the x and y directions.

- https://bl.ocks.org/etiennecrb/863a08b5be3eafe7f1d61c85d724e6c4

But I can't figure out how to pan the axis in the `else` bracket, when the user is just scrolling (without pressing the control key).

I had previously used a separate trigger for `wheel.zoom` but then I need to handle the control key in that other function as well.

I basically want the default zoom behaviors for `mousemove` and when the control key is pressed, but panning rather than zooming on scroll when the control key is not pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am using d3-zoom on this answer as it is more common and part of the d3 bundle. d3-xyzoom, as an add-on module, adds some useful functionality using d3-zoom as a base, so this solution should work with xyzoom with minor revisions - but I don't believe its use is necessary*

The key challenge lies in using the wheel to apply a translate change not a scale change. Roughly speaking, when a scroll event without control occurs you grab the transform on the selection (this should be the node) and update it by taking the scroll and creating an x offset from it to translate the view rectangle. *But*, you don't update the zoomTransform to nullify the change in scale caused by the zoom - so when you pan by dragging, the rectangle changes size because you haven't updated the zoomTransform used by the zoom behavior. Likewise, the translate can be off if it doesn't account for scale.

The disassociation between zoom transform applied to an element as a "transform" attribute and the zoom transform tracked by the zoom behavior is the cause of many headaches on SO - but it allows freer implementation options as one not need use an element's transform attribute to apply a zoom behavior (useful in canvas, zooming unorthodox things like color, etc).

I'm going to propose a basic solution here.

First, the zoom transform tracked by the zoom behavior can be updated by modifying the `d3.event.transform` object itself (or with `d3.zoomTransform(selection.node)` where selection is the selection that the zoom was called on originally).

Secondly, as the `d3.event.transform` object registers scrolling as scaling, we need to override this and convert this scaling into translating - when needed. To do so, we need to keep track of the current (pre-event) translate and scale - so we can modify them manually:

```
// Keep track of zoom state:
var k = 1;   
var tx = 0;

function zoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform;

  // If control is not pressed and a wheel was turned, set the scale to last known scale, and modify transform.x by some amount:
  if(!d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey && d3.event.sourceEvent.type == "wheel") {
    t.k > k ? tx += 40/k : tx -= 40/k;
    t.k = k;
    t.x = tx;
  }
  // otherwise, proceed as normal, but track current k and tx:
  else {
    k = t.k;
    tx = t.x;
  }

  // Apply the transform:
  view.attr("transform", "translate("+[t.x,0]+")scale("+[t.k,1]+")");
  axisG.call(xAxis.scale(t.rescaleX(xScale)));

}
```

Above, I modify the transform t.k and t.k for events where wheeling/scrolling should translate. By comparing t.k with the stored k value I can determine direction: would it normally be a zoom out or zoom in event, and then I can convert this into a change in the current translate value. By setting t.k back to the original k value, I can stop the change in scaling that would otherwise occur.

For other zoom events it is business as usual, *except*, I store the t.x and t.k values for later, for when wheel events should translate rather than scale.

Note: I've set the y scaling and translate in the transform to a hard coded zero, so we don't need to worry about the y component at all.

```js
var width = 500;
var height = 120;

// Keep track of zoom state:
var k = 1; 
var tx = 0;

// Some text to show the transform parameters:
var p = d3.select("body")
  .append("p");  

// Nothing unordinary here:
var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width",width)
   .attr("height",height);
   
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,100])
  .range([20,width-20])
  
var xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale);

var axisG = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate(0,50)")
  .call(xAxis);
  
var view = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height",20)
  .attr("x", width/2)
  .attr("y", 60)

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom",zoomed);
  
svg.call(zoom)


function zoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform;

  // If control is not pressed and a wheel was turned, set the scale to last known scale, and modify transform.x by some amount:
  if(!d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey && d3.event.sourceEvent.type == "wheel") {
 t.k > k ? tx += 40/k : tx -= 40/k;
 t.k = k;
 t.x = tx;
  }
  // otherwise, proceed as normal, but track current k and tx:
  else {
 k = t.k;
 tx = t.x;
  }
  
  // Apply the transform:
  view.attr("transform", "translate("+[t.x,0]+")scale("+[t.k,1]+")");
  axisG.call(xAxis.scale(t.rescaleX(xScale)));
  
  // Show current zoom transform:
  p.text("transform.k:" + t.k + ", transform.x: " + t.x);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```